# How can I get menu items in a Qt Quick application?

Tags: menu, qt, appmenu, qt-creator, qt5

I'm using Qt Creator 3.1.1 on Ubuntu 14.10 (the version installed when you install Ubuntu SDK - the two seem to be the same application). I'm running the default Unity 7 desktop.

When I create a new "Qt Widgets Application", I can add menu items to `mainwindow.ui` via the design interface. They appear in the Unity menu bar (appmenu) when I run the application from Qt Creator.

However, when I create a new "Qt Quick Application" and add menu items to `main.qml`, they do not appear in the Ubuntu menu bar. A new project starts with the following default menu item:

```
menuBar: MenuBar {
    Menu {
        title: qsTr("File")
        MenuItem {
            text: qsTr("Exit")
            onTriggered: Qt.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the project the following error message is recorded:

```
appmenu-qt: handleReparent 136 The given QWindow has no QMenuBar assigned
```

Am I missing a dependency or something like that? Or is this a bug?

Comment: similar problem (no solution): https://forum.qt.io/topic/41504/can-t-get-menu-bar-in-qt-quick-components-using-c-and-qqmlapplicationengine

Comment: It's a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appmenu-qt5/+bug/1323853